# Which city was attacked by Nazi-German war flights in India during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, india, nazi-germany

Nazi-Germany ran a bombing raid over India, in WW2. Which city was bombed, and what effect did it have? i.e how many casualties were inflicted, was transport closed down, or was there other damage to infrastructure?

Comment: Welcome to History.Stack-Exhcange. I've made several edits and changed the question slightly so that it fits the QA a bit better.

Comment: @T.E.D . Yo you are right man. Chennai(Madaras) city was attacked by german warship named "EMDEN". [Chempakaraman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chempakaraman_Pillai) was the person involved in this attack. Some of the unexploded bombs thrown from this ship are still in available in [Government museum chennai](http://www.chennaimuseum.org/draft/gallery/02/04/arms4.htm).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Madras<sup>*</sup> was bombarded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardment_of_Madras) by a German warship during World War I. That's the only instance I could find in either war of an Indian city coming under that kind of fire from German regular armed forces.

Germany had no aircraft carriers, and their only real long-range bomber in WWII, the [Heinkel HE 177](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinkel_He_177), appears to have only been used in the Eastern and Western fronts in Europe. I don't believe Germany ever held any territory that would have been within the HE-177's 5,000 KM operational range from India. (The Eastern Ukraine is a wee bit further than that from New Dehli).

<sup>* - Now [Chennai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chennai)</sup>

Comment: Actually, Germany sent a few planes to Irak to support an anti-English coup, so they were way closer than Ukraine. That said, I found no report of those being used to strike outside Irak, and they did stay in Irak only for a small period before being overrun by the British.

Comment: @SJuan76 - As near as I can tell, the bombers sent there were HE-111s, which had a range in the general vicinity of 2,000 KM. About 3,000 KM would be needed from there. The 177 I mentioned above was not produced until about a year after the end of the insurrection.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom - Pretty much. The captain's rationale is reported in (a translation of) his own words if you click the link at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Agree with TED that German warships did not attack any Indian city. But a thing of interest is that of Japanese warships: **Kakinada** and **Vishakapatnam** were two cities that were attacked by the Japanese in 1942. [It was believed](http://www.thehindu.com/life-and-style/metroplus/memories-of-madras-the-summer-of-1942/article2771785.ece) that Madras would be under attack soon, but it wasn't eventually.

Comment: Quite. If the question was about **Japan**, then the answer gets very different indeed. Particularly if you take "India" to mean the British territory (including Bengal and Burma), rather than the boundries of the modern country.

Comment: The final Japanese offensive to Imphal and Kohima took place in the borders of India and Burma, on the Indian side.

Comment: Japan actually airstriked those cities on 5 April 1942 followed by Colombo.....